# How to migrate postgresql data?

Tags: postgresql, rds, database-administration

I have a on-premise postgresql database and have to migrate its data to aws aurora postgresql.

However the back up is taken using pg_start_backup.

- Can I use pg_restore to restore it?
- Has anyone encountered any issues, What should I be concerned about before doing the restore?
- The pg_start_backup has created separate files, like data.tar.gz,
  index.tar.gz schema.sql , archive.tar.gz and some log files, should i restore all those files (data,index and schema ?)

Answer (score 0):

I heard simply copying all the data files to the new location could replicate the same database, users and settings.